# How to define object within a line of code? (noob)

Tags: objective-c

Sorry for this noob question, but how can i write this in 1 line?

```
NSInteger minuteInterval=5;
[countdownPicker setMinuteInterval:minuteInterval];
```

Thanks

Comment: Why must it be one line of code?

Comment: Because the first line seems superfluous to me, why to create an additional variable to pass a value to the setMinuteInterval method.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. You could use a constant though instead. Your code will not be any less performant and assigning values to well named variables makes your code more readable (avoids ["magic" numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))). In this case of course the meaning of the value is obvious from the method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:
[countdownPicker setMinuteInterval:5];

Comment: Why does this work if setMinuteInterval requires an NSInteger object according to Xcode? Isn't "5" an integer value rather than the required object of class NSInteger?

Comment: An NSInteger isn't an Objective-C object, it's a long.

From [Foundation Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html): 
    typedef long NSInteger;

Comment: @ManuelTrezza The compiler will properly adjust the number literal to the needed type.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger minuteInterval=5; [countdownPicker setMinuteInterval:minuteInterval];
```

Comment: in one line / on one line...

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? The OP said one line, not one statement. This is one line of code.

Comment: I think he means one statement, I doubt that he isn't capable of moving them to a single line.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Until the OP explains the point of this question, we should not make any assumptions.

Comment: Thanks Ramy, that's what I meant, but it was funny to read this answer anyway :)